# JavaFX high memory usage

Tags: memory, javafx, garbage-collection, ram

I'm currently using JavaFX for a 3D-Application (a simple game). I'm displaying a map consisting of blocks where the player can run on. The problem is, when I return to the main menu, the memory allocation is as much as in the game itself (~500MB). So, it seems that Java does not delete the unused references. When I restart the game from the main menu, it goes up to 1GB and so on. I thought the Garbage Collector would take care of those unused references?
I thought that it might be the fact that some objects are referencing each other (through Observer/Observable) so I deleted all observers of all the objects, and I set all the objects to "null". Same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is more likely you have a memory leak somewhere in your game than the garbage collector of java being garbage.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by memory leak?

Comment: Use a profiler, check if any objects are retained after restarting the game. If they're not then it's just java's GC ergonomics keeping the allocated memory around for future use. i.e. it's not really using it. If they are then you're not holding onto objects so the GC can't reclaim them.

Comment: I found the problem. I accidentally added a node multiple times in the same list (and this was in a method which is called pretty often, so the memory usage was high)